# jQuery Firing on.Change Event on each change

Tags: jquery

i am stuck with the following problem. I have a select box that includes Shops. I want to display a different value each time the value of the box changes. The code works perfectly so far, though the on.Change event fires only once, and then does nothing if the value of the select is changed again. Can you point me into the right direction here?

```
<script>
    jQuery(function($){
      $('#shop-select').on('change', function () {
          var url = $(this).val();
          var flyer1 = 'TODO:URL';
          var flyer2 = 'TODO:URL';
          switch (url) {
             case "Shop1":
             url = flyer2
             $('#flipbook-container').html(url);
             break;
             case "Shop2":
             url = flyer2
             $('#flipbook-container').html(url);
             break;
             case "Shop3":
             url = flyer1
             $('#flipbook-container').html(url);
             break;
          }
          return false;
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Does the `html()` call overwrite the original `#shop-select` element and re-create it? If so that's the issue, you need to use a delegated event handler.

Comment: Hi Rory, no all the .html does is adding a tag to an (until then) empty div to show variable content.

Comment: Give your html please

Comment: Why do you have 2 times `case "Shop2":` it will never enter the second case, and in the first 2 case's you are doing the same thing. What do you whant to chage ?

Comment: flyer1 is with the same value as flyer2

Answer (score 0):

If everything is the same nothing will change in the `#flipbook-container` so I've added something different to show you that it enters into change event

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
//if the event is delegated change 
//`$('#shop-select').on('change', function () {` to 
//`$('body').on('change','#shop-select' function () {`
    $('#shop-select').on('change', function () {
        var url = $(this).val();
        var flyer1 = 'TODO:URL';//this is the same with flyer2
        var flyer2 = 'TODO:URL';//this is the same with flyer1
        var value = $(this).val();
        switch (url) {
            case "Shop1": // this case and the next one are the same so don't expect any changes
                url = flyer2;
                $('#flipbook-container').html(url + " JUST TO SHOW IT IS ENTERING here : " + value);
                break;
            case "Shop2":
                url = flyer2;
                $('#flipbook-container').html(url + " JUST TO SHOW IT IS ENTERING here : " + value);
                break;
            case "Shop3":// it will never enter it the case is `case "Shop1":` or `case "Shop2":`
                url = flyer1;
                $('#flipbook-container').html(url + " JUST TO SHOW IT IS ENTERING here : " + value);
                break;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="shop-select">
    <option value="Shop1">Shop1</option>
    <option value="Shop2">Shop2</option>
    <option value="Shop3">Shop3</option>
</select>
<div id="flipbook-container">

</div>
```